# Load external SWF, display it for 5 seconds and then remove it

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i have a Flash Application with a button and an onRelease event. How can i load an external swf File, display it for 5 seconds on top of the main stage and then fade it out? Will this be possible with `createEmptyMovieClip()`?

Answer (score 0):

Load your swf, start a timer , when the timer event fires , fade out the loaded swf , when the fade out is complete, remove the swf.

Answer (score 0):

Use greensock Tween and Loader class. See examples on http://www.greensock.com/